# Select aggregate into Integer using Database.query()

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, aggregate, aggregateresult

So we all know we can put an aggregate directly into an Integer, like this:

```
Integer countAccounts = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account];
```

Is it possible to do the same thing, using Database.query()?

```
Integer countAccounts = Database.query('SELECT COUNT() FROM Account');
```

If so - how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can query using [Database.countQuery(query)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)

```
String QueryString = 'SELECT count() FROM Account'; 
Integer countAccounts  = Database.countQuery(QueryString);
```

Comment: @Semmel Of course it does!